# Selenium PhantomJS is it the same as running IE

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I need to run my Selenium Python test script for IE.
If i ran it using a headless browser PhantomJS, is it going to be different than running it for IE?

I am asking because I am having a problem running my Selenium Python test script from a batch file from task scheduler.
I can run my batch file on it's own and that runs ok.  But when i run it from Task Scheduler the browser does not open so the test fails.
The dev says Task Scheduler runs in the background with a headless browser.
If i used PhantomJS it won't be the same as IE?
I need to test it using IE but the batch file which runs my Selenium test won't open the browser from task scheduler.

My batch file is as follows:

```
set TEST_HOME=%~dp0
cd %~dp0

SET PATH=%PATH%;G:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\IEDriverServer\64bit

cd %~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1

set PYTHONPATH=%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1

c:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests.exe "%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Regression_TestCase\split_into_parts\RegressionProject_TestCase_Part1.py" --with-html --html-file="%~dp0selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport_part1.html"
```

I appreciate some help on this.
Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same as asking, is the ouput the same in IE and in Firefox? Not exactly, visually it will look the same but in the source code some elements are adapted to the browser you're using.

Phantomjs is a browser on it's own, so, some elements can be hidden or not even loaded but it's rare. A good example of this is Twitter. I noticed during some tests that the click on the twit box to write some text behaves differently in phantomjs than in other browsers!

The reason why task scheduler doesn't let you use IE is because you can't use any graphical environments during the lifetime of the proccess.

Comment: I managed to get the Selenium browser IE to open in Task Scheduler. In Task Scheduler to run the task as not hidden the setting radio button "Run only when user is logged on" should be checked.

The browser then open for the Selenium test when the batch file runs.

Many users have faced this issue: I found the solution from here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/why-is-a-windows-7-scheduled-task-running-hidden/d5196c53-5ebd-40a9-8180-d97bde69d060?auth=1

Comment: Regardless or working or not if what you want to do can be done with phantom, I'd use it. Its faster.